# Excel formula drag own changes all cell numbers in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in my sheet (P and Q).
I created a column (AK) with two values in AK2 and AK3, and a column (AL) with two values. One in AL2 and one in AL3.

I am looking to match text in any row of P with one of the two in AK, then pull AL from the same row as the match in AK and populate Q with AL. I hope that makes sense.

This works to do what I want, but when I drag the formula down, it changes the value of each cell in the formula.

=VLOOKUP(P2,AK2:AL3,2,FALSE)

If I drag that down to Q3 it changes to

=VLOOKUP(P3,AK3:AL4,2,FALSE)

The only thing that should change for this formula to work, in my case, is P3.

Appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to freeze the rows with '$'. Something like `=VLOOKUP(P2,$AK$2:$AL$3,2,FALSE)`.

You should look into relative vs. absolute references (see for example [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)), as they are pretty important when using Excel.